# I want to make my every post public

Tags: facebook

I want to make my every post public, and the problem is my every post is public but nobody will be able to comment or like it who is not my friend or who is not following me.

Comment: Check whether you have selected "Limit The Audience for Old Posts on Your Timeline" in your privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this go to settings --> Timeline and Tagging Settings --> Who can add things to my timeline ? --> Who can post on your timeline? to "friends" and check

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a facebook personal page in a manner that might be better suited to a facebook page? Have you considered making a page for you purposes? That way you are generally available to the public and anyone can comment on your posts.